# Boolean basis completeness.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

The task is to check if following basis form complete one in terms of Boolean functions.  $$\{\neg, Maj(x_1,x_2,x_3)\}$$

Maj - Majority function here is equal to the most frequent value among $(x_1,x_2,x_3), e.g: Maj(0,0,0)=0; Maj(1,1,0)=1$

I've only came to Majority function for 3 variables expression in terms of logical functions:
$(x_1\land x_2)\oplus (x_1\land x_3)\oplus (x_2\land x_3)$, however it is hard for me to proceed..

Comment: If $\oplus$ is or, why not use the symbol \vee : $\vee$?

Comment: It is XOR actually)

Comment: Then $Ann(x_1,x_2, x_3)$ is not equivalent to $x_1\land x_2\oplus x_1\land x_3\oplus x_2\land x_3$.

Comment: @OlivierRoche, and what stands for Ann here?

Comment: @AndreasBlass, Maybe we understand different things under Maj? In task condition Maj assumed to be the following symmetrical function: Maj(0,0,0)=0, Maj(1,0,0)=0, Maj(1,1,0)=1, Maj(1,1,1)=1.

Comment: A little remark : In [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majority_function) one finds "For n = 3 the ternary median operator can be expressed using conjunction and disjunction as xy + yz + zx. Remarkably this expression denotes the same operation independently of whether the symbol + is interpreted as inclusive or or exclusive or."

Comment: @James $Maj(1, 1, 1) = 1$ is precisely the case you're missing if you use exclusive or.

Comment: @James You're right. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: @OlivierRoche, but calculating values from left to right after substitution we get: $1\oplus1\oplus1=0\oplus1=1$

Comment: @James my bad, you are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two approaches to proving that negation and majority don't form a complete set.

(1) Both commute with negation. In particular, $\text{Maj}(\neg x,\neg y,\neg z)=\neg \text{Maj}(x,y,z)$. Deduce that the same property holds for any Boolean operation obtainable by composing these.

(2) You can write out explicitly a complete list of the functions of two variables $x,y$ obtainable by iterating $\neg$ and Maj. They are simply $x,\neg x, y, \neg y$. Check that anything obtained by applying $\neg$ to any of these or applying Maj to any of these is again one of these. In particular, you cannot get $x\land y$ this way.

Comment: (1) is so cool!

Comment: And what point one statement about mentioned property for all obtainable boolean operations contradicts to?

Comment: @James Lots of Boolean  operations , like $\land,\lor,\oplus$ don't commute with negation and are therefore not obtainable.

Comment: Got it, thanks!